Computing eigenvalues of a rank 1 matrix
For a fixed vector $\boldsymbol{v}\in\mathbb{R}^d$, I have the matrix $M=\boldsymbol{v}\boldsymbol{v}^\top$, from which I need to recover $\boldsymbol{v}$ (up to sign). I know that $\boldsymbol{v}$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue $||\boldsymbol{v}||_2^2$, and the other $d-1$ eigenvectors are orthogonal to $\boldsymbol{v}$ and correspond to the eigenvalue $0$.
So, it makes sense to try computing an approximation to an eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue. For this, one option is the power iteration method (iteratively pre-multiplying an initial guess  by $M$ and rescaling), which, for my needs is particularly convenient because $d$ is large, so using other methods that involve matrix multiplications is expensive. My question is the following: is there a refinment of the power method that takes advantage of the particular structure of $M$? Or any other method that works with vector multiplications only? Additionally, I am able to compute a good approximation of $||\boldsymbol{v}||$, but it's unclear to me whether this extra information is useful in any way.

Starting from a random vector, the method will converge in at most 3 steps, how much faster do you expect improvements could be?

@LutzLehmann thank you, I wasn't aware of this result!
